# jquery do not show animation on first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slice

New list items are generated by JS.
Each new list item comes in with a nice animation. Now I don't want to see an animation on the first list item.

So far I tried to add `slice(1)` to the code, but no luck:

```
$('li.show').slice(1).animate({left: '-=100'}, 300);
```

How can I make this work using the lastest version of JQuery?

Comment: It seems to be [working fine in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/HtKzq/). Can you elaborate a bit? E.g. what does your CSS look like?

Comment: Posting more of the Javascript code as well as any corresponding HTML would be useful.

Comment: The list items are generated by AJAX, this is probably why it's not working

Comment: @Jroen then you will probably want to put that code inside the ajax callback..

Comment: @amosrivera That's exactly what I did.
$('li.show').animate({left: '-=100'}, 300); works fine. But adding .slice(1) won't do it's magic.

Comment: @Jroen what part does not work? You one any li other than the first to be animated right? That works for me in the jsfiddle posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an AJAX request to build your list then you will need to call the code you posted inside a callback function for the AJAX request so the added HTML will be present in the DOM before you try to manipulate it:

```
$.get('<URL>', function (serverResponse) {

    //append the new list-items to the list, select them, un-select the first index, then animate the remaining elements
    $('ul').append(serverResponse).children('.show').slice(1).animate({left: '-=100'}, 300);
});
```

Note that this code snippet expects your server-side script to output valid HTML that can be added right into the DOM.